# Do you need a stock for carbonade flamande

Tags: beef, stock, french-cuisine, beer

So there is this amazing Belgian/French dish called *carbonade flamande* and as I browse recipes I see one major difference in them: some recipes use (beef) stock while others don't (but then they have larger quantities for beer, or they add apple vinegar, etc…). What is the recommendation regarding the stock while cooking *carbonade flamande*, and is there some "classical way" to cook the dish?

Comment: Thanks for the acceptance. Please let me know if the Carbonade Suisse ended up impressing your guests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm Flemish and I don't use stock at all:

- butter
- half an onion,
- beef
- a nice coat of mustard smeared on top of [peperkoek](https://www.lotusbakeries.be/nl/producten/peperkoek):

  - ginger bread will do nicely as well
  - use "Appenzeller Biberli" if you want to give it a Swiss twist and call it "Carbonade Suisse"
- pepper, salt, nutmeg
- the darkest non-bitter beer you can find (Any [Flemish beer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Belgian_beers) would be better though)...

### :-)

Comment: Also Flemish, and no stock involved. I usually use more onion than @Fabby (depending of course on the amount of meat) and a slice of bread instead of peperkoek and maybe other herbs, but as far as liquids go: only beer (sometimes if it is too runny I add a slurry of flour and water).